# Autoincrement column in oracle using hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

I am using hibernate annotations. I want to make a column as autoincremented. I have created a sequence in database(oracle) and mapped that sequence in java `POJO` class. Do I need to create trigger for that sequence too? I want to know how we can make a column autoincremented  while using hibernate anotation? What changes i have to do in java and as well as database side? Please help me in this. Following is the part of code where I have mapped the sequence.

```
public class SimRuns implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 8698324570356602407L;

    @Id @Column(name = "RUN_ID")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator="seq_run_id")
    @SequenceGenerator(name="seq_run_id", sequenceName="seq_run_id")
    private Long runId;
}
```

Comment: Do you have a trigger/sequence created on the database side?

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(generator = "nosicSeq")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "nosicSeq", sequenceName = "NOSIC_SEQ", allocationSize = 1)
@Column(name = "SID")
private BigDecimal sid;
```

no triggers in DB needed, just sequence.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the generator and setting to auto the generationType

Answer (score 0):

```
@Id @Column(name = "RUN_ID")
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
@SequenceGenerator(name="seq_run_id", sequenceName="seq_run_id")
private Long runId;
```

Hibernate is probably the only JPA Provider that selects the right Generationstrategy based on your databasetype. Using the `GenerationType.AUTO` statement hibernate will try to select the best strategy to implement an increasing row id.

Answer (score 0):

1. In Oracle :  It's no need for an Oracle trigger, but the sequence is must.
2. In pojo: you can use Annotations like this:

   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator="majorsSeq")
   @SequenceGenerator(name="majorsSeq", sequenceName="MAJORS_SEQ", allocationSize = 1,initialValue = 1)
   public int getId() {
       return id;
   }